# Tiki Torch Fuel - removal of permeatting odor in interior car

Tags: smell

Spilled 1/2 gallon of tiki torch fuel in back passenger floor. Soaked carpet and underlayment. Smell still identified on inside doors; ceiling; dashboard etc. What is the best way to dissiminate the smell? Is the product still flammable?

Comment: The carpet and underlay are likely still flammable. The smelly elements are cedar oil and citronella are not very volatile and will likely take a long time to disperse even if well-ventilated

Comment: Put some Kitty Liter or Oil Dry ( same product) down to absorb oils/fuel. After it sits a few days ,vacuum it away. repeat as wanted.

Comment: @blacksmith37, why not post this as an answer? (Comments are for improving questions, and can be deleted without notice at any time.)

Answer (score 2):

Put some Kitty Litter or  Oil Dry ( same product) under and on the carpet. Let sit a few days then vacuum it out . Repeat as needed . It will draw out most of the oil.